# How do you save a mass, search through it by indicator and then display the required object data?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting data via Websocket from Binance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoKwZ.png)

```
{
  "e": "aggTrade", // Event type
  { "E": 123456789, // Event time
  "s": "BNBBTC", // Symbol
  "a": "12345", // Aggregate trade ID
  "p": "0.001", // Price
  "q": "100", // Quantity
  "f": 100, // First trade ID
  "l": 105, // Last trade ID
  "T": 123456785, // Trade time
  "m": true, // Is the buyer the market maker?
  "M": true // Ignore
}
```

I'm trying to record each new message in the history and then find and display the price that was 10 seconds ago each time.

```
{
  let currentMessage; 
  let history = [];
  let nPeriod;
  let socket = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/dogeusdt@trade");
  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    currentMessage = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log("Current data", currentMessage);

    history.push(currentMessage); 
    console.log("history", history); 
    nPeriod = currentMessage.T - 10000;

    for (let i = 0; i < history.length; i++) {
      if (history.includes(history[nPeriod])) {
        console.log("Price from history 10 seconds ago", history[[p]]);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

But I can't understand why I can't find the price that was 10 seconds ago.

Comment: `history[[p]]` why is did you do `[[]]` with the extra `[]` and what is `p`?

Comment: `history.push(currentMessage);` is pushing in an object. Not sure what `history.includes(history[nPeriod])` is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Messages have not an exact frequency, so you can't find a message from 10-seconds ago looking at the timestamp.  You may need to find the newest message from 10 seconds ago instead.

This is the code example with additional log information.

```js
var history1 = [];


var currentMessage; 
var nPeriod;
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/dogeusdt@trade");
socket.onmessage = (event) => {
  currentMessage = JSON.parse(event.data);
  console.log("Current data", currentMessage);

  history1.push(currentMessage); 
  //console.log("history", history1); 
  nPeriod = currentMessage.T - 10000;

  for (var i = history1.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    // message time before 10 sec ago
    if (history1[i].T <= nPeriod) {
      console.log("Price from history 10 seconds ago", history1[i].p, " Current:", currentMessage.p);
      break;
    }
  }
};
```